# input field as drop down

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to make an input field a drop-down list as well. I have seen a few examples of what to do but yet when I mimic them I still have 2 separate fields for the data to go. I also have a problem with the datalist not displaying properly. Any ideas or routes to try would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="input-group">
     <label class="input-group-addon tc-group-addon" data-translate="" title="{{$tcore.tcoreTranslations.TRANSLATIONS.elementList.ThinClient_TIS.translation_184}}">
         TRANSLATIONS.elementList.ThinClient_TIS.translation_184
     </label>
     <input list="valueLists" ng-model="vm.selectedValue" class="form-control tc-tis-form-control" ng-change="vm.changeValue()" ng-disabled="vm.readOnly">

     <datalist id="valueLists" ng-model="vm.selectedValue" class="form-control tc-tis-form-control" ng-change="vm.changeValue()" >
          <option ng-repeat="item in vm.valueList" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
     </datalist>
```

What I am trying to mimic is this functionality where you can type inside the box or you can choose a predetermined value [I want to mimic this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)
[image: Drop-down list error]

[image]

Comment: _datalist not displaying properly._ what is the definition of properly and whats the actual problem?

Comment: In the part that I circled that is the data that I want yes but, it's not displaying properly as in it shows all the values even before I select the drop-down and displays it behind everything. As shown 2 values are hidden by the user data input. it should be contained within the value drop down menu that isn't even focused on at the time and it's showing the values. If I use the select property tag instead of datalist it displays two input boxes. Well on input box and one drop down list box.

Comment: I added a second picture to show the differences I am getting when I use the "select" tag it properly displays the list BUT! it is giving me 2 different boxes one input field and one drop down list.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a `typeahead` type solution? Sorry not clear what your goal is.

Comment: My goal is to make the input box and the drop-down box one box. Where you can type if you want to enter a custom amount or you can use the drop down to select a predefined value. Not necessarily a `typeahead` solution but a `combo box` solution maybe?  [This is an example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)